# Animation didn't work properly when click the button in menu

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n1ssf5up/5/

I took the source code from this link: http://codepen.io/MrBambule/pen/jIseg

I need to change the code for getting small size button.

It works fine, when i increase the font-size, as `0.7em to 1.7em` for the list.

css:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2E3F47;
  z-index: 10;
}

.line {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 15px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.line__first {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

/* for the list to be horizontaly centered */
.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu__list {

  width: 100%;
  margin-left:-110px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

/* Animation keyframes for the drop down */
@keyframes drop {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    top: 85px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    top: 70px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    top: 85px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    top: 70px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu__list__item {
  opacity: 0;    
}

/*Animation classes to add to list-items that should be animated*/
.list--animation, .list--animation--delay1, .list--animation--delay2 {
  animation: drop 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation: drop 0.9s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list--animation--delay1 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.list--animation--delay2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

I need same animation and with small size button.

may i know how to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no button in your code , that is a div.

Comment: yes,,  that is a for showing button

Comment: ok then what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: i need same as this link http://codepen.io/MrBambule/pen/jIseg .. but only reduce the size of button.

Comment: Ok check this https://jsfiddle.net/n1ssf5up/6/ and let me know are you looking for this change

Comment: I did reduced the size.. but still i am struggling in animation.. you too do the same @arun. in your fiddle also animation didn't work properly.. i need like this link http://codepen.io/MrBambule/pen/jIseg

Comment: no the same animation is happening there too, change the fond size and animation speed and try

Comment: can you please provide the jsfiddle ?.. may i know, why it is not possible?

Comment: yes you are right, now i noticed the difference

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
.line { background: #ccc;width: 30%;height: 16%;margin: 10% auto;}     line__first {  margin-top: 15%;}
```

Comment: i need to increase the font-size..

Comment: the font size of "menu__list__item"?

Comment: i try with this:
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

Comment: ok now I understand.
you have to change the "top: 85px;" parameter in

Comment: @-webkit-keyframes drop {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    top: 185px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    top: 70px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

Comment: see if this works : 
https://jsfiddle.net/n1ssf5up/5/

Comment: see your jsfiddle.. animation is not correct ya..

Comment: i need same animation like this https://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/n1ssf5up/8/

Answer (score 0):

check out this

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/n1ssf5up/8/)

You have to add class with delay in jQuery code..

```
  $('.item1').addClass('list--animation');
      $('.item2').delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('list--animation--delay1').clearQueue();
    });
       $('.item3').delay(2000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('list--animation--delay2').clearQueue();
    });
```

Change in CSS

```
.list--animation--delay1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

.list--animation--delay2 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: with this, i need, increase the font-size of lists..

Comment: what font-size you want exactly

Comment: for this li a {}.. if i increase the font-size, animation didn't work properly..

Comment: are you there @uiupdates

Comment: Yaa..I got some office work so will solve in it later time sry..

Comment: its ok... but please don't forget to solve.. thanks

Comment: @rani https://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/n1ssf5up/9/ check this fiddle link I hope it works now with large font-size..

Comment: super.. @uiupdates. how to animation delay time reduce?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70844/discussion-between-uiupdates-and-rani).